# Python For Loop and Data Type Explanation please

Tags: python, string, for-loop, int, user-input

I am creating a python program that creates an xhtml table for websites based on a variable value.

please look at the following two codes. The second one does not work.

```
rows = int(input('How many rows would you like? '))
for i in range(rows):
    print 'lol'

rows = raw_input('How many rows would you like? ')
int(rows)
for i in range(rows):
    print 'lol'
```

even though i have properly stated that the `rows` variable is being changed to an integer, why doesn't the `range` function accept this, and treat it as as integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i have properly stated that the rows variable is being changed to an
>   integer

**No**, rows is not being changed to an integer. Just applying `int(rows)` on `rows` does not change the `str` object `rows` to `int`. But it **returns** an `integer` object.

You would either need to store the return value in a variable, and use it. Or, directly use it in `range` function.

```
int(rows)
for i in range(rows):  // rows used here is still a string
```

The above code should be: -

```
for i in range(int(rows)):
```

Answer (score 0):

The **int()** method does not modify *in-place*. Instead, it *returns a modified copy* of the parameter you specified leaving the parameter (rows) unchanged.

```
>>> rows = "45"
>>> i_rows = int(rows)
>>> type(rows)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(i_rows)
<type 'int'>
```

When you simply type **int(rows)** as in line 6 of your code fragment, the result is returned to the stack or, if you're using the [interactive shell](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html), then it is output immediately to the terminal.